# Wide to Long Dataset in SAS

Tags: sas, data-cleaning

I have a dataset that has multiple measures taken as multiple time points.

The data look like this:

```
 UserID Var1_2008 Var1_2009 Var1_2010 Var2_2008 Var2_2009 Var2_2010 Race
  1      Y        N         Y         20        30        20        1
  2      N        N         N         15        30        35        0
```

I want the data to look like this:

```
 Year UserID Var1 Var2 Race
 2008 1      Y    20   1
 2009 1      N    30   1
 ....
```

How can I do this? I'm totally lost

Comment: Have you looked into PROC TRANSPOSE at all? Please post anything you've tried as well.

Comment: Like I said, I'm totally lost. Proc transpose didn't look like it would work because I have the multiple variables and I need the new year variable.

Comment: Yes, but SO isn't really designed to answer those types of questions then. One of the requirements for a question, is to post something you've tried not just post a full question and get an answer. You have an answer below, but it won't generalize past your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array, assuming you have the same years for all of the `var1_` and `var2_` variables.

```
data want ;
  set have ;

  /* Need two arrays, as one is character, the other numeric */
  array v1{*} var1_: ; /* wildcard all 'var1_'-prefixed variables */
  array v2{*} var2_: ; /* same for var2_ */

  /* loop along v1 array */
  do i = 1 to dim(v1) ;
    /* use vname function to get variable name associated to this array element */    
    year = input(scan(vname(v1{i}),-1,'_'),8.) ;
    var1 = v1{i} ;
    var2 = v2{i} ;
    output ;
  end ;

  drop i ;
run ;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a macro for that! I think running the following will do exactly what you want to accomplish:

```
    filename ut url 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FriedEgg/Papers/master/An_Easier_and_Faster_Way_to_Untranspose_a_Wide_File/src/untranspose.sas';
    %include ut ;
    %untranspose(data=have, out=want, by=UserID, id=year, delimiter=_,
       var=Var1 Var2, copy=Race)
```

Comment: the one above worked, but I'm going to play with this too!